# Google Analytics: How to generate a unique visitor's User ID? AND add it to the Tracker code

Tags: php, google-analytics, userid

According to google...**I need to generate my own user ID's**
[image: screenshot]

And then add `ga('set', 'userId', {{USER_ID}});` to my **Tracker code...**

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXXXXX-X', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

---

### Question 1) How to generate my own user ID?

Right now my code looks like (`include ('google-analytics.php')`) this:

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '<?=$seo['analytics'];?>', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

How do I get php (or javascript) to generate a unique id, **by site visitor (NOT by clicks)**?

In other words, if the same visitor clicks on several pages within the site, I want the ID to **remain the same ID** and not chage with every click (or refresh).

I tried `$seo['userID'] = uniqid();` but it changes with every click or refresh.

---

### Question 2) Where to insert it, within the tracker code?

I have no idea where to place `ga('set', 'userId', {{<?=$seo['userID'];?>}});` within all this...

```
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', '<?=$seo['analytics'];?>', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');
```

...tracker code.

AND if this `ga('set', 'userId', {{<?=$seo['userID'];?>}});` is the right way to code it, or this `ga('set', 'userId', <?=$seo['userID'];?>});`, or this `ga('set', 'userId', <?=$seo['userID'];?>);`, etc...

Comment: 1- you have a log in system? use an id from that. 2. add it to the end with those other *ga* values

Comment: then you dont have a unique user id system- so i dont understand how you expect this to work.

Comment: The recommenended format is uuid (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier), however you seem to be missing the point with Googles user id feature. Setting it via clientside code will simply replicate the function of the client id which is already in place (if you insist on using the feature you might as well use that).

Comment: without a login system you can't. As far as your site knows every 'hit' is from a 100% unique human.

Comment: There is nothing in GA that allows you to "zero in to specific people" (in fact that would violate the TOS). You have a device specific client id (which is set by default), and you may set a user id from a backend system - the purpose is to unify sessions from different devices into a single user (but the GA interface will not allow you to "zero in" on that user, the user id is by default not exposed in the interface. And you must not use an id that allows a third party to identify a person).

Comment: if you dont mind how unreliable they are you could use a cookie.

Comment: For example, how to accomplish it with this: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/cookies-user-id